# Reliable JTAG debugging setup for R Pi 3B+?

Tags: pi-3b+

I have recently purchased a RPi 3B+ board as I need to debug a bunch of code on Arm Cortex A53. It is essential to be able to step through the code, insert breakpoints, read registers, memory, etc, but in a comfortable, productive way - so I need to debug using JTAG and an IDE tool; no time for command line gdb-ing. For my software development I use Windows + Eclipse + GCC toolchain.

Before going any further with my projects, I need to confirm if my setup will work with any JTAG debuggers out there? I am willing to invest some moderate amount of money (up to 1000 $, maybe even more if the tool will save me the setup time). However, I would like to stay on my current "Windows + Eclipse + GCC" software setup.

Please advise?

Comment: Ohhh do Raspberry Pi have a JTAG!?! Have you looked through the specification?